# Activity draws the Red square everywhere when I touch on the app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, touch

Suddenly app draws the **Red square** everywhere when the user touches inside the app.

**Some common inputs**

- It happens in my application only, not any other application.
- It happens in every device irrespective of the OS version also.
- Tried out the Clean / Make / Build project. no effect.
- Tried to trace the dispatchTouchEvent(MontionEvent ev) but no luck.
- Android studio version: 3.3
- Gradle version: 3.0.1

It was working fine on 4th March. Getting the issue from the 5th March.
Please ask for more details if required. Find the screenshot here.

[image]

[image]

Any help, feedback, suggestions will be appreciated.